# Difference between INTERNAL SD CARD and Internal storage.

Tags: android, smartphone

I m confused abt the difference between "INTERNAL SD CARD" and "Internal storage". 
I have 12 GB shown as INTERNAL SD CARD and 1 GB as Internal storage in "storage" settings of android.There's NO Micro SD card inserted.I didnt attach any external micro SD card.

I find "move to tablet" and "move to SD card" options for the applications installed.
My Internal storage is almost occupied, so I wanted to move app from "Internal storage" to "INTERNAL SD CARD" using "move to SD card" option but it says "not enough storage"."INTERNAL SD CARD" has 100 mb available. Why cant I move data between these two internal storages.

Answer (score 17):

The storage in your device is partitioned, so as example I have 32GB of storage:

```
name | fs type | size
```

`/system | ext4 | 591MB`: is the partition where the ROM is stored, it's mounted read only so you can't normally write there

`/data | ext4 | 1.5GB`: is the partition called "Internal storage", it's used to store apps and it's data.

`/storage/sdcard0 | vfat | 27GB`: it's an emulated sd card, so even if it's part of the same physical storage it's seen by the os as an sd card.

then there are other minor partitions.

Some manufacturers choose to not enable move to sd card for the emulated sd card, some enable it, it's not a bug just a choice.

As for your question, you didn't mention how big is the app you want to move and also to move an app to sd android creates a file that it's an encrypted ext4 filesystem which contains the app, so it might require more space than the original app size plus maybe there are checks to leave some free space in the sdcard.

To have a quick look at how your storage is partitioned you can install from Play Store "Partition Table" or the program mentioned by @Lunation Studios

Comment: I think your answer is more accurate, hence upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

*Your Problem is that some Android devices treat the Internal Storage as a SD Card.*

In your case: 
your Internal SD Card is your entire phone storage, where your system, data and frameworks are placed. Internal Storage is the part of your Internal SD Card, which you can access 
(without rooting the device).

So, thats why you cannot move your apps. It is a bug, that you can still select "move to sdcard". For this you need a real EXTERNAL SD CARD.

Comment: -not 100% sure, but try a Storage Analyser (Play Store) to understand-

Comment: @Tanvir, no its not a bug. Some apps are officially supported to be moved to SD card/internal Storage. 
When you move an app to SD Card, the app (most of it, and it's data) is moved from the `Android/app` partition of your device to your internal storage, both of them being part of your total phone memory.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps are officially supported to be moved to SD card/Internal Storage.

When you move an app to SD Card, the app (most of it, and it's data, including the update files) is moved from the `Android/app` partition of your device to your internal storage, both of them being part of your total phone memory.

Previously, Android used to create a folder named `.android-secure` in your main storage.

The storage that you see available in Android, is like a drive of a disk. In which you store PDFs, Movies, Music, etc.
When you plug in device to a computer, this is the storage which you will see as mounted. This is the storage to which you can copy videos, music, etc.

However, on the same disk of the phone that comes as is (w/o putting external sd card), Android creates partitions, like `system`, `etc`, `data`, etc. These are also on the same disk.

Just imagine a hard disk with windows, and moving a program from `C:\program Files` to `D:\` where you have more space. `D:\` is the space where you can copy things and store pictures, etc. Its your storage that is made available to you.

This is the storage with maximum size, and is also called **Internal Storage/USB Storage**. So if your phone tells that you have less memory to install apps, since your `app` partition is limited in size, you can move big apps like Angry Birds, Gameloft Games, etc. to **internal storage**, meaning in the space that you store your data, which is visible on connecting to computer - and can then conveniently install more apps in the `app`

Putting an external memory card is like adding a new hard disk to your computer. On which you cannot move apps officially. 
However, if rooted, you can `symlink`, meaning create links to external sd card with more storage, and let Android think that this is Internal SD card.

Answer (score -1):

Internal memory is your Read Only Memory for operating system and system files etc. SD Card is the External SD Card storage memory which isn't embedded inside the phone and which you might buy separately and slide it in the external SD Card slot allocated on your phone .

Comment: THNX to all of u guys I found that every app is installed in "internal storage" and there's NO OPTION for "move to sd card" for those apps. That means its kinda forcing me to install app in the limited 1GB "internal storage", though it has another 12GB as "internal SD card" , what to do.... sigh!!

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Internal storage is not all read only, rather it refers (primarily) to the /data partition where apps and their private data ate stored.